# Pango-ERROR: Harfbuzz version too old (1.4.2)

Tags: software-installation, electron, pango

I was trying to run [this](https://github.com/mkermani144/wanna/) application but this error occurs on the startup of the application, is there a way to avoid this?

(wanna:90765): Pango-ERROR **: 03:53:41.569: Harfbuzz version too old (1.4.2)

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: it's Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This Help? https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20348

Comment: Not much, I checkout that link myself some time ago but there wasn't a clear answer.

Comment: The electron version being used by that app needs to be updated for it to work. Update the repo, or update the versioning, if there is a newer version.